# how do I make a TileGroup layout that has the jaggy edge on top?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, tilelist, gumbo

I have spark.components.TileGroup that contains buttons.

I would like the buttons to appear like tabs on top of the ViewStack they serve

At the moment, if I have 6 items in the TileList it lays it out as 2 rows with 4 items in the top tow and 2 in the bottom, so the jaggy edge is at the bottom

```
[ITEM 1][ITEM 2][ITEM 3][ITEM 4]
[ITEM 5][ITEM 6]
```

I would like it to look like this, with the jaggy edge on top

```
[ITEM 5][ITEM 6]
[ITEM 1][ITEM 2][ITEM 3][ITEM 4]
```

The order of the items is not important

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a new layout that lays the tiles out the way you want.

some links to get your started.
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/spark_layouts.html
http://insideria.com/2009/05/flex-4-custom-layouts.html